# MBP works fine but not visible on network

Tags: macbook-pro, network

I have a strange problem, that for the life of me I can't seem to resolve.  I'm hardly a newbie to this type of stuff, which is making the lack of success even more frustrating/embarrassing :)

I have a pretty much pure-Apple setup:  two AirportExtreme routers (one acting as a range extender for the first), two MacbookPros, two iPhones, iPad etc.  Love my toys.

However my one MBP does not seem to be visible from the network.  I can ping anything from anything else, with the exception of this one MBP.  The machine is of course connected and working fine.  It can also ping everything on the network.

I've used a static IP so that I can be sure I'm pinging the right machine.  I've also checked that the firewall is (Preferences -> Security -> Firewall) turned off.

What else do I need to check to diagnose this?

Comment: What about other services, can you for instance turn on file sharing and manually connect via cmd K?

Comment: Did you check that the pinging has nothing to do with the range extension of the airportextremes? E.g. are you experiencing the problems, when being connected internet-ae-ae-mbp or when connected internet-ae-(mbp & ae)? I am assuming that the range extension is not forwarding all information and this is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So, Broken MBP can ping anywhere, including other machines in your network, but can it ping itself?  (You have to read that with the "Will it Blend?" sound)

The rest of the machines can ping each other, but not the Broken MBP.

Am I correct?

Does this only happen via Wi-Fi? Have you tried using a Cable?

What happens if you turn ON the firewall and make sure that in "Advanced" the machine is not in Stealth Mode:

[image: icmp]

(Security -> Firewall -> Advanced)

Comment: Thanks for your response Martin.

I plugged Broken MBP in a hardwired connection, and gave both interfaces a static IP.  Neither IP is pingable from another device on the network.

I did try the firewall with Stealth mode off, but the result is the same :(

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is some restrictions on Wi-Fi services in OS X. I have hade the same problem but when I used cable ethernet connection - all went OK.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the range-extending Airport Extreme from the setup, and turn off all other devices except for the two laptops, just for troubleshooting purposes.

Then I'd set both laptops to normal DHCP, not static IP addresses, in case this was causing a problem, then see whether the "healthy" laptop can ping the "unhealthy" laptop.

Check that the "System Preferences --> Sharing --> FileSharing" is enabled, and check through the options, shared folders, and users to make sure that anonymous users can see the files you are trying to share.

If all of this works, then I'd slowly add devices one by one, until I'd found which one was causing the problem, and troubleshoot further from there.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently and wasted a lot of time on it only to find out that my MBP was connecting to the guest network from my Time Capsule.

Answer (score 0):

Can you

- ping other devices on the network from the broken MacBook?
- from another computer, ping all devices but just not the broken MacBook?

If both of the above are true there must be a firewall somewhere blocking icmp pings to the broken macbook. Maybe on the airport? Have you reseved the mac address for this macbook? Otherwise double check the network settings. DHCP or static won't make any difference. DHCP is not going to change that often.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this might help someone.

Go to your preferences > click on Sharing > turn File Sharing on.

Happy sharing